# ng-repeat for table when getting generic array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where i am doing common reusable table structure using directive where i am getting different json data which i need to repeat it in table header as well as table body

Controller code:

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.firstJson=[{name:"abc1",empid:10215},{name:"abc2",empid:10216},{name:"abc3",empid:10217},{name:"abc4",empid:10218},{name:"abc5",empid:10219}];
  $scope.secondJson= [{product: "mobile", price: "10000"}, {product: "camera", price: "12000"}];
  $scope.name =  $scope.firstJson;
  $scope.tableHeading=["heading1","heading2","heading3"];
  $scope.toggle=true;
}
```

Here i have two Jsons and can be used any where in the application and json keys should be table head and values should be in table body

Directive Code:

```
    angular.module('plunker').directive('sampleDirective', function(){

  return {
    // restrict to an element (A = attribute, C = class, M = comment)
    // or any combination like 'EACM' or 'EC'
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      name: '=',
      tableHeading:'='
    },

    templateUrl: 'reverse_template.html',

    replace: true, //replace the directive element with the output of the template.
    //the link method does the work of setting the directive
    // up, things like bindings, jquery calls, etc are done in here


  };
});
```

Please refer plunker link 
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/48wIZjO47XKbus5s8fwh?p=preview)

Final output for firstJson[image]

Final output for secondJson[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please show us the final result ? You have 3 headings but 4 kind of data

Comment: @Weedoze
U could see the Json structure there and the keys should be repeated in table head and values should be repeated in table body.

It doesnt have fixed  no.of keys for table head ,Json will be generic

Comment: can you give a screnshot of how final result should look because your questiona and plunker are vaguely constructed

Comment: @Shikhathakur Why do you have 2 JSON ? Are they linked ? If yes, how are they linked ? Why are you only sending the `firstJson` array ? Why do you have a `tableHeading` array if you only display the key as the column name ?

Comment: @Angular_10
I have updated my question

Comment: @Weedoze
I just want to make my table common for any kind of json structure

Comment: @Shikhathakura this is clearer now

Comment: @Shikhathakur I am working on something

Comment: @Shikhathakur If my answer helped you It would be great to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second array are the arrays you provided with 2 columns.

I added a third array to show you that it also works with 3 columns.

It will actually work no matter the number of columns or rows

*Note : replace the templateURL to the right file and move what is inside `script ng-template` to your external file*

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstJson=[{name:"abc1",empid:10215},{name:"abc2",empid:10216},{name:"abc3",empid:10217},{name:"abc4",empid:10218},{name:"abc5",empid:10219}];
  $scope.secondJson= [{product: "mobile", price: "10000"}, {product: "camera", price: "12000"}];
  $scope.thirdJson = [{name: "a", price : "50", quantity : "3"}, {name:"b",price:"60",quantity:"2"}];
});

app.directive('sampleDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "reverse_template.html",
    replace : true
  }
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3>First json</h3>
  <div sample-directive data="firstJson"></div>

  <h3>Second json</h3>
  <div sample-directive data="secondJson"></div>
  
  <h3>Third json</h3>
  <div sample-directive data="thirdJson"></div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="reverse_template.html">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
           <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">{{value}}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </script>
  
</body>
```

Comment: For a long time been through NG I didn't know it is possible to access  an item on a array using this approach **data[0]** inside a template, wonderful. Adds up to my knowledge.

Comment: @Preenz No matter if you are inside a template or whatever. You can access an item inside an array with its index

Comment: I was used to using data.key in a template and didnt stumble something like that

Comment: this is a nice answer !

Comment: @Angular_10 Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could think of for your problem is to separate column entry based on the keys of your array of objects then dynamically display rows based on columns. Here is an example on how it works:

your directive

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    columns: '=',
    rows   : '='
  },

  replace: true,

  link: function ($scope) {

    $scope.displayData = function (row, column) {
      return row[column];
    };
  }
};
```

and your HTML would look like this:

```
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns>{{displayData(row, column)}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in your JS would be

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [
    {
      'column_1': 1,
      'column_2': 2,
      'column_3': 3
    },
    {
      'column_1': 1,
      'column_2': 2,
      'column_3': 3
    }
  ];

  $scope.columns = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
}
```

Tip if you want to dynamically extract keys from an array of objects just simply get 1 item then get its attributes and put to **$scope.columns**

example:

```
var extractAttributes = function (object) {
  var attrs = [];

  angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
    attrs.push(key);
  });

  return attrs;
}
```

Tip: You can also do the column separation in the directive by using **$watch** when row data is updated then extract the columns from there.

Hope that helps

Comment: All this code is not necessary. You can simply work with the array directly

Answer (score 0):

I went for this approach

```
<div>
  Hello, {{name}} ,{{tableHeading}}

 <table ><tr><th ng-repeat="(key,value) in name[0]">{{key}}</th></tr><tbody><tr ng-repeat="names in name"><td ng-repeat="(key, value) in names">{{value}}</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/48wIZjO47XKbus5s8fwh?p=preview)

Comment: see my answer if that fits you